# Uniform convergence of parametrised Fourier series.

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

Let $X$ be a compact topological space, and $f: S^1 \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a *continuous* function. Then for every point $x \in X$ we can compute the Fourier coefficients
$$c_k(x) = \int_{S^1} f(z,x) z^k \text{d}z,$$
and construct the Fourier series as the limit of the partial sums
$$s_n(z, x) = \sum_{k=-n}^n c_k z^k.$$
This  must not converge point-wise, but taking [Cesàro means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation)
$$ \sigma_l(z,x) = \frac 1 l\sum_{n = 0}^{l-1} s_n(z,x) = \frac 1 l \sum_{n=0}^{l-1}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}c_kz^k = \sum_{k=-l}^l\frac{l - |k|}{l}c_kz^k,$$
we get uniform convergence in $z$ by  [Fejér's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r%27s_theorem).

Note that $\sigma_l(z,x)$ is still continuous in $x$.

In his book *K-Theory*, Atiyah claims that the $\sigma_l$ converge uniformly in $x$, that is given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $l_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, such that for all $(z,x) \in S^1 \times X$ and $l \geq l_0$ we have
$$\|f(z,x) - \sigma_l(z,x)\| < \epsilon .$$

I don't have any idea why this should be true, but my knowledge about Fourier series and analysis is pretty limited. Any help would be appreciated.

Here are some thoughts I had:

- One obstacle is that the $\sigma_l$  do not form a true series, because of the factor $\frac  1 l$. So the classical Weierstrass test does not even apply here. Is there another kind of *Weierstrass test* that one could apply to this situation?
- Because $X$ is compact, it would suffice to show uniform convergence locally.